# Display orders with a custom status for "all" in Woocommerce admin orders list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have created few custom order status using this code

```
 register_post_status( 'wc-arrival-shipment', array(
        'label'                     => 'Shipped but not paid',
        'public'                    => false,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped but not paid<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped but not paid <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
```

All is running good except of all orders listing. it shows the correct count all(3) but in the listing you will only see 1 order and it is not displaying all 2 other orders which has been updated into the new custom order status. 1 order is displaying only which is on-hold only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the problem, you need to add your custom order in wc_order_statuses filter hook too…

At the same time it can be useful to have it displayed in bulk actions dropdown.

The complete code:

```
// Add custom status to order list
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 10 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-arrival-shipment', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Shipped but not paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped but not paid<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped but not paid <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}

// Add custom status to order edit page drop down (and displaying orders with this custom status in the list)
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses' );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-arrival-shipment'] = _x( 'Shipped but not paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status  to admin order list bulk actions dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_arrival-shipment'] = __( 'Mark Shipped but not paid', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: You saved my life Sir... Thank you so much from my bottom of the heart :)